# Alamofire request coming up nil

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm developing an iOS app which user WebServices and I find Alamofire just perfect for what I'm doing but I'm having a problem; the app asks the user to login which is an Alamofire call and does it just fine.

The problem is, it has to create a collection view based on the content of another Alamofire request but is always `nil`.

```
    func getJSON(URLToRequest: String) -> JSON {

    let comp:String = (prefs.valueForKey("COMPANY") as? String)!
    let params = ["company":comp]
    var json:JSON!

    let request = Alamofire.request(.POST, URLToRequest, parameters: params).responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                json = JSON(value)
            }
        default:
            json = JSON("");

        }
    }
    debugPrint(request.response)

    return json;
}
```

The same codeblock works perfect for the Login but doesn't in this case BTW the debug Print always print `nil`

[image: Debug Print]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access to `request.response` before it has been set, remember that Alamofire works **asynchronously**, so you have to return in your case the JSON using closures, but remember that Alamofire also returns an error, so I strongly recommend use the following code instead:

```
func getJSON(URLToRequest: String, completionHandler: (inner: () throws -> JSON?) -> ()) {

   let comp:String = (prefs.valueForKey("COMPANY") as? String)!
   let params = ["company":comp]

   let request = Alamofire.request(.POST, URLToRequest, parameters: params).responseJSON {
    response in

    // JSON to return
    var json : JSON?

    switch response.result {
    case .Success:

        if let value = response.result.value {
            json = JSON(value)
        }

        completionHandler(inner: { return json })

    case .Failure(let error):
        completionHandler(inner: { throw error })
    }
}
```

The trick is that the `getJSON` function takes an additional closure called `'inner'` of the type `() throws -> JSON?`. This closure will either provide the result of the computation, or it will throw. The closure itself is being constructed during the computation by one of two means:

- In case of an error: `inner: {throw error}`
- In case of success: `inner: {return json}`

And then you can call it like in this way:

```
self.getJSON("urlTORequest") { (inner: () throws -> JSON?) -> Void in
  do {
     let result = try inner()
  } catch let error {
     print(error)
  }
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: this works just perfect!! thanks a lot; but you see I'm kinda new with Swift and the code loses me in the "inner:() throws -> JSON?" part

Comment: You're welcome, there is another way you can use just returning a closure with the JSON but I think this is the best because let you catch the error in the process, the closures are hard topic at the beginning, but once you got it it's a powerful tool. The `(inner: () throws -> JSON?` it's just a function which return a `JSON?` or throws an error just that, nothing more don't be afraid