# Swift Variable Values and Functions

Tags: swift

I have a piece of code in which an optional is initialized and is then assigned a value in a function but is `nill` when unwrapped?

```
var datastring: String?
Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://example.url/request", parameters: parameters) .response { request, response, data, error in
    datastring = NSString(data: data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String // there is data in here
    // textView.text = datastring!  datastring is not nill when here
}    
textView.text = datastring! // datastring is nill when here
```

This is not Alamofire specific. I have come accross this issue when using native Swift methods. What am I doing wrong and why does Swift work this way?

PS. I'm still learning :)

EDIT: Thank you to all who helped me. To clarify the problem, it was a question of transferring a variable's value from an asynchronous thread to the main thread. I just didn't know how to word that.

Comment: datastring is being set inside of a callback (asynchronously). In the meantime, the main thread has continued to run so your variable doesn't have anything in it when textView.text is set. You need to pass your value back to the main thread in another callback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alamofire request coming up nil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372850/alamofire-request-coming-up-nil)

Comment: @ohiodoug Thank you for explaining that. That is what I didn't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're updating the `datastring` variable in a closure. That's code that is passed to Alamofire to be executed later (microseconds later perhaps). So the line assigning `datastring` to the `textView` happens first, before the closure executes.

Try this instead:

```
var datastring: String?

Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://example.url/request", parameters: parameters).response { request, response, data, error in
    datastring = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        textView.text = datastring
    }
}
```

Using the `dispatch_async` call ensures the UI update happens on the main thread.

It's possible that network request won't happen for several seconds (or longer), so you may want to update the UI with a temporary string so the user sees something while waiting.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. Your's and @ohiodoug's explanations helped me a lot. Marking this the answer because the dispatch_async what I need to get back to the main thread.

Comment: Awesome, glad to help. Also, since you're new to Swift, try and avoid using `!` as much as possible. You should consider every use of `!` as a possible crash point. My team actually calls them `crash bangs`.

Comment: @DaveWood, `crash bangs`--I like that. (Oh, and hello.)

Comment: @NRitH oh hey old teammate! How goes it?

Comment: BTW, credit goes to @clstroud for the term `crash bangs`. :)

Answer (score 0):

These two lines

```
datastring = NSString(data: data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String // there is data in here
textView.text = datastring! // datastring is not nill when here
```

are *not* run immediately, since they are inside a closure. It's up to Alamofire to decide when to run the closure.